# My Raspberry Pi B+ has the Ri 2 B pinmap

Tags: pi-2, led, java, pi-b+, pi4j

I trying out different java programs for my RPi B+ V1.2 and as far I have only tried to blink with a lamp for a few seconds. It works.

Now I want to try to blink with a lamp by using a button. In this case, I need to use a listener for my button.

I have been using this java code from this [page](http://pi4j.com/example/listener.html):

```
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.*;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.event.GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.event.GpioPinListenerDigital;

/**
 * This example code demonstrates how to setup a listener
 * for GPIO pin state changes on the Raspberry Pi.
 *
 * @author Robert Savage
 */
public class ListenGpioExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("<--Pi4J--> GPIO Listen Example ... started.");

        // create gpio controller
        final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();

        // provision gpio pin #02 as an input pin with its internal pull down resistor enabled
        final GpioPinDigitalInput myButton = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_02, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN);

        // set shutdown state for this input pin
        myButton.setShutdownOptions(true);

        // create and register gpio pin listener
        myButton.addListener(new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
            @Override
            public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
                // display pin state on console
                System.out.println(" --> GPIO PIN STATE CHANGE: " + event.getPin() + " = " + event.getState());
            }

        });

        System.out.println(" ... complete the GPIO #02 circuit and see the listener feedback here in the console.");

        // keep program running until user aborts (CTRL-C)
        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }

        // stop all GPIO activity/threads by shutting down the GPIO controller
        // (this method will forcefully shutdown all GPIO monitoring threads and scheduled tasks)
        // gpio.shutdown();   <--- implement this method call if you wish to terminate the Pi4J GPIO controller
    }
}
```

This listener won't even print out a single message from the method **handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent**

I have WiringPi installed:

[image]

I'm trying connect GPIO_02 to 3.3v but nothing happes:

[image]

Have I forgot something? It was a long time ago I worked with microcontrollers. Mabey I have missed something?

One weird thing is that if I write this command:

[image]

Then GPIO18 will go HIGH/LOW and ligth a LED lamp.

Then I tried this pinmap

[image]

And now it wokring.

**Question:**

Why does my Raspberry Pi B+ has the Raspberry Pi 2 B pinmap?

Comment: All Pi with the 40 pin header have IDENTICAL header - these are the same

Comment: @Milliways But why does it differ for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me you're mixing up pin numbering schemes.

The B+ image above shows BCM (Broadcom) scheme.

The second one is the wiringPi (and implicitly Pi4J) scheme (notice the text at the bottom of the image). The `gpio` utility, which is part of wiringPi, also uses this scheme by default.

Use https://pinout.xyz/ for reference.